# Rate limiter not working

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

The following code has an expected duration of 1000ms.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var start time.Time
    for {
        start = time.Now()
        connect()
        fmt.Println("Duration", time.Since(start).Milliseconds(), "ms")
    }
}

func connect() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(1), 1)
    // Wait for the rate limiter to allow the request
    if err := limiter.WaitN(ctx, 1); err != nil {
        remainingTime := limiter.ReserveN(time.Now(), 1).Delay()
        time.Sleep(remainingTime)
    }

    nodeURL := "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/your-infura-project-id"
    client, _ := ethclient.DialContext(ctx, nodeURL)

    // Use the client to interact with the Ethereum network
    // Example: Retrieve the latest block number
    blockNumber, _ := client.BlockNumber(ctx)

    fmt.Printf("Latest block number: %d\n", blockNumber)
}
```

Gives me the following output:

Latest block number: 0
Duration 251 ms

Latest block number: 0
Duration 250 ms

Latest block number: 0
Duration 243 ms

Latest block number: 0
Duration 243 ms

Latest block number: 0
Duration 243 ms

Latest block number: 0
Duration 244 ms

Any clue what wrong with my limiter?